# different types of null,how to deal with it in mybatis?

Tags: spring, oracle, null, mybatis

I am doing some web development based on Freemarker+Spring+MyBatis+Oracle.Now I am facing a very simple but hard problem,that is, how to deal with different types of 'NULL':

For example , a table stores information of many students,one row for a student including his name, his class number and his teacher(we assume that he has only one teacher).

**NULL 1**:we want to find students of class three , so our query condition becomes {class_number='3'}.In this condition ,our query becomes:

select s * from student_table where  class_number='3'

MyBatis config file can be like this:

```
<select id="selectStudents" parameterType="map" resultType="map">
       select  * from student_table a where 1=1 
       <if test="class_number!= null">
       and a.CLASS_NUMBER= #{product_name,jdbcType=VARCHAR}
       </if>
      <if test="teacher_name!= null">
       and a.TEACHER_NAME= #{teacher_name,jdbcType=VARCHAR}
       </if>
</select>
```

Yes , it is what we want.

**NULL 2**:for history reasons, some rows's teacher_name is null,it means that the teacher of this student is unknown.we want to find these students whose teacher is unknown.Obviously , the xml file above cannot meet our demands.we should modify it like this:

```
   <select id="selectStudents" parameterType="map" resultType="map">
           select  * from student_table a where 1=1 
                <choose>
       <when test="class_number!=null &amp;&amp; ques_type!=''">
       and a.CLASS_NUMBER= #{class_number,jdbcType=VARCHAR}
       </when>
       <otherwise>
       and a.CLASS_NUMBER is null
       </otherwise>
       </choose>

   <choose>
       <when test="class_number!=null &amp;&amp; ques_type!=''">
       and a.TEACHER_NAME= #{teacher_name,jdbcType=VARCHAR}
       </when>
       <otherwise>
       and a.TEACHER_NAME is null
       </otherwise>
       </choose>
    </select>
```

If we have both query requirements in a single system, what should I do ?

Comment: You need to refine your question. It is quite clear what your question is.